# How do I place a read lock on MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, locking, database

My application needs to access a Mongo db where if more than one process/thread is reading from a specific collection, bad things will happen.

I need to restrict the ability of a group of processes to read from the collection (or db, if need be). So for example, if there are multiple processes trying to read from the db, they read sequentially, *not* in parallel.

Comment: Bad things will happen if more than one process is _reading_ from a collection? That sounds like an unusual situation, can you tell us more?

Comment: @VinceBowdren yes. The documents that are in the collection determine the next document to be placed in the collection. There must be no duplicates placed in the collection. So if two processes are reading from the collection concurrently, they could read the same data, compute the same next document, and then both write the same document, which is bad for my algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done in the driver level. If you set connection pool size to 1 then all access to to database will be in sequence.

In nodejs you can set the driver as:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, {  
  poolSize: 1
});
```

From the documentation:

> poolSize, this allows you to control how many tcp connections are
>   opened in parallel. The default value for this is 5 but you can set it
>   as high as you want. The driver will use a round-robin strategy to
>   dispatch and read from the tcp connection.

Comment: Does this work even if multiple `MongoClient` instances are initiated in different processes? For example, if two processes both run `MongoClient.connect(url, {poolSize: 1});`, will the database still accept connections from the TWO processes sequentially? @kozakvoj

Comment: No, but if you really need sequential access to your database (and it's unusual situation as @VinceBowdren mentioned) you can use a message queue. Your threads can delegate db read to the queue which will notify them back when it's done (asynchonously).